# Minecraft launcher giving Java error "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Tags: java, minecraft, openjdk

On Ubuntu 17.10, the Minecraft launcher keeps giving me "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty" error. The full log is here:

```
user@hostname:~$ java -jar Downloads/Minecraft.jar 
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is Oct 11, 2017, 10:48:39 AM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '4.13.0-12-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '9-Ubuntu'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 2/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 3/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 4/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 5/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 6/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 7/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 8/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 9/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma (try 10/10)
Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to download while being forced
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:95)
    at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)


Please fix the error and restart.
```

I have tried the Minecraft launcher from both the Minecraft website and from ppa:flexiondotorg/minecraft.

I have tried openJDK-8, openJDK-9 and Oracle Java 8, all giving me the same error.

A similar problem was posted a while ago here: [Minecraft with OpenJDK 7, I get "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627426/minecraft-with-openjdk-7-i-get-the-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty).
The best solution seems to have been to run `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`. However, running this command does not solve the issue for me.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in [A.B.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/627451/301745) on the linked question?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it didn't work at the time. I did manage to get Minecraft running, though, by doing [ashermaster's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/628245/745316) in the same thread. I fired up an Ubuntu 16.04 VM and replaced my cacerts file from the one I copied from there. Now, I don't get the error anymore, even if I rerun 'sudo update-ca-certificates -f'.

Still, I feel as if I didn't really solve the issue, just bypassed it...

Comment: OK, great that you got it working!