# Ubuntu 17.10 Java 8 Certificate Error

Tags: java, compiling, 17.10

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10, on which I installed the package oracle-java8-installer (from PPA).

But when I try to compile an ionic project using "ionic cordova build android", it throws this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1916)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1899)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1420)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:91)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>
    (PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:89)
        ... 26 more
```

I am connected to the internet and I tried to:

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates -f
$ sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates-java
```

...and also reinstall npm, ionic, java and gradle, all with no success.

**edit:** I also have ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME exported in .bashrc, and Android Studio installed. I have tried to build the project on a different machine and it works fine. I can't try using OpenJDK because it doesn't work well with Android Studio.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates-java
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
```

to get broken cacerts fixed.
For me, this fixed it.
Good luck!

Comment: Worked for me as well for openjdk-9! Any explanation as to why this works when `--reinstall` and manually running the postinstall script did not? I'm very interested for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: OMG.  I've been looking for this answer for weeks.  Every other answer to this question I've found did nothing - absolutely nothing.  This worked perfectly.  Something seems pretty broken with these certs on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Fixed Jenkins on 17.10 too. Thanks (and upvoted)

Comment: Thanks very much worked for me with gradle (4.5.1) and open-jdk-9. Did not work with the oracle-jdk-9 though.

Comment: Solution for Ubuntu 18.04. I installed openjdk version 11. Because of Android I had to additionally install openjdk 8. For unknown reason installed cacerts file by openjdk 11 doesn't work with openjdk 8. I had to uninstall both jdks and install only version 8 and then regenerate the cacerts file.

Comment: Also did't work with default-jre (openjdk 10.0.1 2018-04-17).